# vercel deployment error FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

Tags: python, flask, vercel, itsdangerous

there i was trying to deploy my flask application when i deployed my app i go this error

In logs

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous' (/var/task/itsdangerous/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

In Front end

```
This Serverless Function has crashed.

Your connection is working correctly.

Vercel is working correctly.

500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: bom1::***********************
```

*Logs Error*[Logs error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Fkq.png)

i am using python i got this error because of this module `itsdangerous==2.0.0`

i also tried after Removing the version constraint for itsdangerous but i got tge same error

```
[21:39:17.324] Installing required dependencies...
[21:39:53.728] Failed to run "pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt"
[21:39:53.729] Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
[21:39:53.729] ERROR: Cannot install -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt (line 14) and itsdangerous==2.0.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
[21:39:53.729] ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```